# Excel VBA unhide sheets based on list of sheet names if it meets certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below which unhides the sheets if they appear in a list between B4 and B35.

I need to add a kind of if statement that if in the adjacent column it says "reserved" then don't unhide it, otherwise unhide it. I think the code I need is something like...

```
If UCase$(Nm.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> "RESERVED" Then
    If UCase$(Nm.Offset(0, 1).Value) <> "2" Then
```

however I am a bit confused how to include it within the code. Is there also a way to stop the second click of the button from re-hiding everything, presumably that's something I've accidentally set up within the code. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Button5_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim shList As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cost Tracking")
shList = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("b4:b35"))

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, shList, 0)) Then
        sh.Visible = Not sh.Visible
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below unhides worksheets, based on the following criteria:

- the name of the worksheet is in Range("B4:B35") of the `Cost Tracking` worksheet.
- two columns to the right the word `RESERVED` is not present.

---

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Tracking")
    Set myRange = ws.Range("b4:b35")

    For Each myCell In myRange
        If Not IsEmpty(myCell) _
            And Not IsError(WorksheetExists(myCell.Value2)) _
            And UCase(myCell.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "RESERVED") Then

            Worksheets(myCell.Value).Visible = True

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Not WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Evaluate("'" & sheetName & "'!A1"))
End Function
```

Concerning the additional conditions, like hide and unhide, you may consider checks such as:

```
If Worksheets(myCell.Value).Visible = xlHidden Or _
Worksheets(myCell.Value).Visible = xlVeryHidden Then
    Worksheets(myCell.Value).Visible = xlVisible
Else
    'something else
End If
```

*(I have not tested the code, but it should be working...)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, however I am running into problems with the following line as it says subscript out of range, any ideas why this might be? thanks                Worksheets(myCell).Visible = True

Comment: @Charlotte879 - I guess I have not written `.Value`, thus it does not accept range argument. I have edited.

Comment: I have tried this again and again I know I am missing something really simple but still getting the same error that subscript is out of range. When I hover over the debug it just says myCell.value = empty 
Guessing it can't find the my cell part of the code but not sure why!

Comment: Can't express how much I appreciate your help! So grateful. I am recieving a different error now which makes me hopeful! it says WorksheetExists.. compile error, sub or function not defined. Have you seen that one before not sure how to correct currently trying to google!

Comment: @Charlotte879 - I have deleted by mistake the `WorksheetExists` function on the last edit, I have added it.